# Easy way to get rid of trailing escape characters

Tags: python

I'd like to know WHY this works!

I have this text from an email, (supposed to be answers to a multi-choice test, I'm just trying it out.):

`'1825010101,徐豆豆,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\r\n\r\n'`

The email program must add the `"\r\n\r\n"`, because I did not.

I was trying all kinds of tricks to get rid of `"\r\n\r\n"` like:

```
> text.strip(['\\r\n\r\n'])   
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
>     text.strip(['\\r\n\r\n'])   
TypeError: strip arg must be None or str
```

By chance I typed `text.split()` without anything and, lo and behold, they were gone!

So I quickly did

```
textCut = text.split()  
saveText = ''.join(textCut)
```

and I'm back to my original input.

Why does this work?

Comment: The split() method splits a string into a list.
You can specify the separator, but the default separator is any whitespace.

Comment: All you need is `saveText = text.strip()`

Comment: More precisely `saveText = text.rstrip()`

Comment: if you did `text.strip()` like @user9074332 wrote, or `text.strip('\r\n\r\n')` even without `[]` then it would've worked.

Comment: Aha, I should not have used [ ]?? That was how it was written on the webpage I looked at, so I thought the [ ] were obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `strip` is the function you're looking for.

> Strip: Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Try `replace`

```
text = '1825010101,徐豆豆,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\r\n\r\n'
print text.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
> 1825010101,徐豆豆,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument you are passing to the strip function is an array:

```
strip(['\r\n\r\n'])
```

Instead, pass a string:

```
strip('\r\n\r\n')
```

Comment: yeah, sorry, just a beginner with python. I saw it like that on a webpage, I thought the [ ] had to be there!